# android : How to know about a new process start in device?

Tags: java, android

I am writing a program which respond when a new process got start.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

            // what to write here

        }
    };
```

I do not know that what to write instead of comments to get processes info.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't monitor process starts using a BroadcastReceiver. You should look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29): you would have to run it in a loop, but that's probably your best bet.

Comment: ok but this will give the Running app process but how come I know that a new process is added in the list ...

Comment: You'll have to run it in a loop: there is no way in the published Android interface to be notified everytime a process is created. You could try setting a timer to check for new processes every 5 seconds, for example.